# jQuery validation - errorPlacement is breaking code

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

As soon as I insert `errorPlacement:` function, it breaks the code. No validation happens on click of submit. can someone help please.

If I remove this function, validation works fine.

**Imports:-**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

**Script:-**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#post-an-ad").validate({
            rules:{
                articleTitle:{
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },            
                dateRequested:{
                   required: true,
                    date: true
                },
                articleLocation:{
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8
                },
                'user.agent': "required",
                'user.firstName': "required",
                'user.emailId':{
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                'user.phone':{
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8,
                    number: true
                }
            },
             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
             alert("This alert is not popping");
             },
            submitHandler: function(form){      
            // doing nothing on a submit.
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put your code into a jsFiddle and it crashed my browser.  Your Validation code is fine... however, putting an `alert()` inside the `errorPlacement:` function is **not**!

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    alert("This alert is not popping");  //--- this is causing infinite loop
},
```

Alert is triggered on error, then when you hit "ok" on alert it's re-triggered immediately since the form is still invalid, the process repeats... this gets stuck in infinite loop of non-stop alerts.  It crashed my Safari because I could not dismiss alert without next alert popping back immediately.  I'm sure other browsers are handling this loop in their own way.

Everything else is working fine.

Un-comment the offending lines at your own risk:

http://jsfiddle.net/59bsp/

---

This is the solution where `errorPlacement:` works perfectly fine...

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element);  //- this line demonstrates the default behavior
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59bsp/1/